# How to reduce number of injected constructor arguments

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, autofac

I am using Autofac for Dependency Injection. But the problem with Autofac is that the number of Injections(Variables) in the constructor is increasing with the size of the project.

Is there a way to reduce the number of injections with Autofac or if there is another library that can help to reduce it.

Thanks!

Comment: This is more of a design problem than a framework problem. You will have the same problem with every dependency injection framework. A component should not have so much dependency, you should refactor your component to have less dependency. You can find more information here : https://blog.ploeh.dk/2018/08/27/on-constructor-over-injection/

Comment: How is it possible to reduce the count ? Is there a way to acheive it considering the fact that those dependency are required. Is there to combine them in a single variable .

Comment: Look at the previous link and read about [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) and [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID). There is no single recipe to achieve a good design. It is not that easy and require some experience but if you understand the SOLID principle you will quickly get good design

Comment: Also take a look at the concept of [Facade Services](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/02/RefactoringtoAggregateServices/).

Comment: Number of injections is not a problem as such, but rather a consequence of not following SOLID principles (especially single responsibility). The moment you sort your responsibilities, number of injections should reduce greatly.

Answer (score 0):

You should only load the needed dependencies in a class. If it's some kind of a switching amount of parameters you need, maybe load them in the needed methods instead.